# DateTimeInput is being rendered as simple text input in django

Tags: html, django, datetime, html-input

I have tried to take date time input from the user but data type of date input is being set as type="text"

following are the code snippets:

template:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-DOS9W6NR+NFe1fUhEE0PGKY/fubbUCnOfTje2JMDw3Y=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" integrity="sha256-FEqEelWI3WouFOo2VWP/uJfs1y8KJ++FLh2Lbqc8SJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.stayFrom}}
    <script>
         $(function () {
         $("#id_stayFrom").datetimepicker({
             format: 'd/m/y',
             });
         });
      </script>
</form>
```

forms.py:

```
class RoomApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    stayFrom = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%y'])
    class Meta:
        model = Stay 
        fields = ('stayFrom')
```

models.py:

```
class Stay(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)

    stayFrom = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="stay start date")
```

heres the rendered html:

```
<input type="text" name="stayFrom" id="id_stayFrom" autocomplete="off">
```

can you point out what i'm missing in my code?

Answer (score 3):

The default widget for [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield) is a text field ([DateTimeInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateTimeInput)). So this is expected behavior.

Comment: What change do I do to make its type="date"

Comment: I would point out that you are using a datetime field, so probably use `datetime-local` type, or update the field class

Comment: You have to override the default widget and set the `attrs` value in the widget input, e.g. - `forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#widget
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
stayFrom = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%y'])
```

Do:

```
stayFrom = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'date'}))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).