# Date field not appearing in a Django form

Tags: django

I have created a Django form which almost works correctly

All of the fields appear with their Labels and Help Text.

If I define the Field type as *Dropdown* it works perfectly, But if I define a field as *Date* it just seems to act as a normal *Single line text*.

(A form with html

```
<input type="date" id="today" name="today">
```

works perfectly in the browser so that isn't the problem. This form is not based on a model, it was just to check that the browser does show date fields correctly in a form.)

Here is the model for the template

```
from django.db import models

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (
    FieldPanel, FieldRowPanel,
    InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel
)
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.contrib.forms.models import AbstractEmailForm, AbstractFormField


class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    page = ParentalKey('FoodDiaryPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='form_fields')


class FoodDiaryPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    template = "food_diary/food_diary_form.html"
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text', classname="full"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel('subject'),
        ], "Email"),
    ]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please include your form and template when it works and when it doesn't.

Comment: Can you please include the model and form you constructed?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Qusetion updated

Comment: Expected as per design - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389224/datetimeinput-is-being-rendered-as-simple-text-input-in-django/60389863#60389863

Comment: Django adds `Date`, `Time`, `DateTime` inputs as `text` type `input` tag in HTML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTimeInput is being rendered as simple text input in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389224/datetimeinput-is-being-rendered-as-simple-text-input-in-django)